# Trying to append to Iterable[String]

Tags: scala, iterable

I'm trying to add another string to Iterable[String] for easy concatenation, but the result is not what I expect.

```
scala> val s: Iterable[String] = "one string" :: "two string" :: Nil
s: Iterable[String] = List(one string, two string)

scala> s.mkString(";\n")
res3: String =
one string;
two string

scala> (s ++ "three").mkString(";\n")
res5: String =
one string;
two string;
t;
h;
r;
e;
e
```

How should I should I rewrite this snippet to have 3 string in my iterable?

Edit: I should add, that order of items should be preserved

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`++` is for collection aggregation. There is no method `+`, `:+` or `add` in `Iterable`, but you can use method `++` like this:

```
scala> (s ++ Seq("three")).mkString(";\n")
res3: String =
one string;
two string;
three
```

Comment: FWIW we *should* be able to just do `s + "three"`, but due to the ubiquitous `+`  operator injected by `Predef.any2stringad` we end up with string concatenation instead of appending. You'd normally use `:+` and `+:` instead, which will disambiguiate the call, but sadly they are present on `Seq` but not `Iterable`. This is in fact consistent given that `+` is not defined on `Iterable` either, but has the unfortunate effect that attempting to use `+` on an `Iterable` will lead to an an expected result (as opposed to appending to the iterable or just not compiling, which would both be preferable)

Answer (score 5):

The `++` function is waiting for a `Traversable` argument. If you use just `"three"`, it will convert the String `"three"` to a list of characters and append every character to `s`. That's why you get this result.

Instead, you can wrap "three" in an `Iterable` and the concatenation should work correctly :

```
scala> (s ++ Iterable[String]("three")).mkString(";\n")
res6: String =
one string;
two string;
three
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use toBuffer and then +=

```
scala> val l : Iterable[Int] = List(1,2,3)
l: Iterable[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val e : Iterable[Int] = l.toBuffer += 4
e: Iterable[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

or in your example:

```
scala> (s.toBuffer += "three").mkString("\n")
```

I have no idea why this operation isn't supported in the standard library. You can also use toArray but if you add more than one element this will be less performant - I would assume - as the buffer should return itself if it another element is added.